# How can I record as MIDI track a live performance in MainStage 3 (MIDI piano)

Tags: garage-band

I usually use Garageband as piano sequencer but Mainstage 3 has a much better piano so I want to try recording and reproducing my piano MIDI tracks using Mainstage 3.
What is the recommended approach to record my piano performance in Mainstage but not as an audio track?

As an alternative, I have read that I can use Mainstage sounds in Garageband but at least in last versions (Garageband 10.3.2 and Mainstage 3) I can't seem to find Mainstage piano sounds (Steinway and Yamaha grand pianos) in Garageband. Any directions on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can’t record MIDI in Mainstage. I’m not sure that you can even record audio, but I know you can play it back.

I haven’t found an easy way to use Mainstage sounds in GarageBand. I believe the intention there by Apple is that you would upgrade to Logic Pro, which will include all the Mainstage sounds and let you record, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try to find a way to run Garageband and Mainstage together so I can at least record the MIDI track in Garageband.